# Android service for infinite time whether application is on or off

Tags: android, android-service, background-process, daemon, android-service-binding

I am newbie to Android and creating application to share files. I want to create a service which will check in db that anyone has asked for any files or not for infinite time whether application is on or off. Inshort, I want to create a service same as any normal messanger to check whether any message has come or not. Please suggest me anything in this direction. Any help appreciated.

Comment: My service should check every 1 min that any request for user has come or not. If there is any request, my service would start downloading process. I have created service in my application but if I remove background process in phone, my service is getting destroyed. I just want to be careful that service should not destroy in any circumstances.

Comment: In short, I want the same kind of service as WhatsApp do for checking messages.

Comment: consider using a push notification instead.

Answer (score 1):

Override as shown below onStartCommand in your service class file

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Next there are chances that your service will be destroyed by android due to low memory for that use Alarmmanager and get alarm callback for every one hour

context.startService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));

```
    public void setAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, "1234", intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mAlarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000 , alarmIntent);
    }
```

Comment: start your service in Receiver everytime....If your Service is active then no issues if not your service will be recreated.

Comment: I have receiver which will be called when connectivity change occur. how to check whether service is active or not? Where to put above setAlarm method?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. Actually I need to integrate Google FCM push notification in my application. I was unaware about that so that I was thinking about checking same thing in my phone. I was wrong about that. At last I got my answer. Thanks a lot for kind support.